# \surroundwithmdframed does not sourround \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, mdframed

I need to surround code listings with a customized gray `mdframed`.

To do this I use the very convenient macro

```
\surroundwithmdframed[options]{environment}
```

to instruct that all `lstlisting` environments have to be surrounded with an `mdframed`.

While this works fine for listings inside a `lstlisting` environment, it does not work for listings loaded from a file with `\lstinputlisting`.

How can I tell `mdframed` to also surround the listings loaded with `\lstinputlisting`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %  gray color for code background

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{codeframe}{
  backgroundcolor=light-gray,
  linecolor=light-gray,
  roundcorner=5pt
}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
}

% This tells mdframed to surround every lstlisting environment.
\surroundwithmdframed[style=codeframe]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}
    
    % This listing is surrounded with an mdframed.
    \begin{lstlisting}
    foo
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    % But this one is not!
    \lstinputlisting{foo.txt}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Handling verbatim material is not an easy matter, so no wonder it does not work. May I suggest you have a look at tcolorbox instead. Not only is it far more advanced and flexible compared to mdframed, it also have build in systems to deal with listings.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for suggesting `tcolorbox`, it worked! See my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619288/98306).

Answer (score 1):

Following [@daleif's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619278/surroundwithmdframed-does-not-sourround-lstinputlisting#comment1546329_619278) I switched to [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) and was able to get the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %  gray color for code background

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{code/.style={
  boxsep=1pt,
  boxrule=2pt,
  arc=3mm, 
  auto outer arc,
  colframe=light-gray,
  colback=light-gray,
  listing only
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{code}
foo
\end{tcblisting}

\tcbinputlisting{code,listing file=foo.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this requires a whole change of package. Is there any way to import the file into `lstlisting` environment?